# how to do frame by frame animation in opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

Can anyone guide me for animation in opengl. I have tried using normal frame by frame animation and using canvas but i have some drawbacks as i need to merge two bitmap as single bitmap and make animation so now i trying to attempt to use opengl.
I have tried this code

```
   img.setOnClickListener(this);
    int reasonableDuration = 50;
    mframeAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    mframeAnimation.setOneShot(false);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame1, reasonableDuration);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame2, reasonableDuration);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame3, reasonableDuration);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame4, reasonableDuration);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame5, reasonableDuration);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame6, reasonableDuration);
    mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame7, reasonableDuration);

    moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(400, 0, 0, 0);
    moveLefttoRight.setDuration(3000);
    moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);

    img.setBackgroundDrawable(mframeAnimation);

    mframeAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
    //If this line is inside onClick(...) method of a button, animation works!!


}
```

after googled i got a above code normal frame by frame animation but here i need to stop animation at certain point so i need to go for opengl. Please guide me..

Comment: Did you able to do frame by frame animation using openGL ES in android...if please share your experience .

Answer (score 1):

I been reading about that lately and what i can do for you is forward to this links:

http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/
http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development

Not sure if that is what you are looking for but hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have to merge two bitmap to make a single image and have to animate frame by frame. i am spending whole day for this till i didnt get solution. please help me.

Comment: I'm actually not really helpful in opengl. I just read some blogs and watched some vids few days ago. I thought those links would help you in your problem but i see it's not enough. You need to learn the basic stuff first like drawing triangles i guess.

Comment: don't interpret me wrong, i'm just saying that i would start with the basics first. As @datenwolf said you mixed things

Comment: i know how to use opengl at basic level. above code was written for normal frame by frame animation but i have to use animation using opengl..

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake lies in mixing event handling with animation iteration. Usually you have some display function that gets called in a loop. Prior to each display iteration you advance the animation state and have the display function render the scene in the current state.

The event handlers OTOH just trigger animations, but don't animate them.